# Find the count of events preceding a given date that varies

Tags: r, data.table

I'm using the data.table package in R. Let's say I have the following data.

```
dt = data.table(id = c(101,101,101,101,
                       102,102,102, 
                       103,103, 
                       104,104,104,104),
                date = c("2016-01-01","2016-02-01","2016-02-01","2016-03-01",
                         "2016-05-01","2016-06-01","2016-08-01",
                         "2016-01-01","2016-03-01",
                         "2016-01-01","2016-02-01","2016-02-01","2016-03-01"),
                event = c("inbound call","rescheduled","scheduled","completed",
                          "inbound call","rescheduled","scheduled",
                          "incomplete","scheduled",
                          "inbound call","rescheduled","scheduled","inbound call"))
dt
```

I would like to find a count of the total number of inbound calls for each member that occurred prior to the schedule date event.

If I just wanted the total number of inbound call for each id, I could do the following.

```
dt[event=="inbound call", .N, by = id]
```

However, this would be wrong for some member id's. For example, the count is 2 for id 104 because they've had 2 inbound calls. However, only 1 occurred prior to the scheduled date, so it should be 1

How they can I set up the logic where I get a count of the inbound calls that occurred prior to the scheduled event.

Desired output is this

```
id    num_inbound_calls
101   1
102   1
103   0
104   1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible approach with `data.table`:

```
dt[, num_inbound_calls := cumsum(event=="inbound call"), id][event=="scheduled"]
```

output:

```
    id       date     event cs
1: 101 2016-02-01 scheduled  1
2: 102 2016-08-01 scheduled  1
3: 103 2016-03-01 scheduled  0
4: 104 2016-02-01 scheduled  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way with `dplyr` -

```
dt %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(
    calls = sum(event[1:which.max(event == "scheduled")] == "inbound call")
  )

# A tibble: 4 x 2
     id calls
  <dbl> <int>
1   101     1
2   102     1
3   103     0
4   104     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another version with `dplyr` assuming you will have at least one `"scheduled"` for each `id` is to `slice` rows till 1st `"scheduled"` for each group and then count number of `"inbound call"`.

```
library(dplyr)

dt %>%
  arrange(as.Date(date)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice(seq_len(which.max(event == "scheduled"))) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(event == "inbound call"))

#    id     n
#  <dbl> <int>
#1   101     1
#2   102     1
#3   103     0
#4   104     1
```

---

A base R option using combination of `ave` and `aggregate`

```
aggregate(event~id, dt[with(dt, ave(event == "scheduled", id, 
  FUN = function(x) seq_along(x) <= which.max(x))), ],     
        function(x) sum(x == "inbound call"))

#  id  event
#1 101     1
#2 102     1
#3 103     0
#4 104     1
```